# Using a theorem to tell a function is integrable or not.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

I don't know how to utilize this theorem

> A bounded function $f:\left [ a,b \right ]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is
> integrable iff $\forall \varepsilon ,\exists $ partition $P$ s.t
> $U\left (f,P  \right )-L(f,P)< \varepsilon $.

to this problem

> Define $f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if }
>  1-2^{-2k}\leq x\leq 1-2^{-(2k+1)} \text{ for } k=0,1,2,...\\  0 &
>  \text{ if } 1-2^{-(-2k+1)}<x<1-2^{-(2k+2)} \text{ for } k=0,1,2,...\\ 
> 0 & \text{ if } x= 1 \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$ , and compute
> $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$.

We denote $U(f, P)$ as the upper sum, and $L(f, P)$ as the Lower sum.

I thought I could disprove this problem as follows.

> Suppose $f$ is integrable function on $[0,1]$.
>
> And, let's suppose we have only 1 partition $[0,1]$.
>
> $\Rightarrow \forall k, U(f,[0,1])=1 \;  \text {and} \; L(f,[0,1])=0$
>
> $\Rightarrow U(f,[0,1])-L(f,[0,1])=1$
>
> Since $f$ is integrable, we can take $\varepsilon =\frac{1}{2}$ by the
> theroem above.
>
> However, for $\varepsilon =\frac{1}{2}$, there does not exist any
> partition because $U(f,[0,1])-L(f,[0,1])=1$.
>
> Hence, $f$ is not integrable, so we can't compute
> $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$.
>
> $$\blacksquare$$

But, of course, there must be a significant error in this disproof because of my misunderstanding of the theorem, but I don't know which part I don't understand.

Can I get some enlightenment to understand how the theorem is used to prove this kind of problem?

Comment: Forgive me because this might look like a silly question.

Comment: For some $\epsilon>0$ you proved the existence of a partition that "does not work", but so what? That does not prove that partitions that "do work" do not exist. Note that it all starts with $\forall\epsilon\exists P\dots$. So with existential quantor for the partition.

Comment: @drhab Oh so, you mean we can always construct partitions that depend on epsilons? For example, if we take epsilon as 1/2, we can always make some finer partitions. In other words, the construction of partitions is flexible. Is it what you meant?

Comment: Sort of, yes. If for every $\epsilon$ you can find a partition $P_{\epsilon}$ such that ... then things are okay. The partition somehow "depends" or is "tailored" on $\epsilon$. We are dealing with $\forall\epsilon\exists P$ and not with $\exists P\forall\epsilon$.

Comment: @drhab Thank you very much!